# MS Test manger not able to stop a test and re-start with attachments taken

Tags: test-management, mstest, mtm

Is there a way when using test manager to stop a test part of the way through close down test manager and continue the run at a later date with the attachments you have taken?

Comment: Out of curiosity why would you want to do this?  Are you trying to use the test to generate data you would use in later tests?

Comment: Dan the reason for this is sometimes a more 'important' test needs to be run and would like to park one you are halfway through and then pick up later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pause the test run, then save and close. All the attachments you've created to that point will be saved.

When you're ready to come back to the test, you'll need to return to the point you left and located the unfinished run (Test > Analyze Test Runs), then Resume.

You should be able to pick up where you left off.